# Find the $LU$ decomposition of the matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given the matrix $B$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
2 & 3 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and I would like to find the $LU$ decomposition of $B$. I use row operations to obtain the matrix

$U$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4  
\end{bmatrix}$.

I apply these same operations to the matrix

$Z$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 & & 1  
\end{bmatrix}$ to get the matrix
$L$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0 \\ 
 -2&-3 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}$.

I'd like to know if my $L$ and $U$ in this given decomposition problem are correct?

Comment: $LU$ should equal $B$ which it doesn’t, so it’s wrong.

Comment: That's true. Although, a lot of time would have been saved had someone pointed out that one must apply reverse row operations on $Z$ in order to get the correct matrix $L$.

Comment: Like ten seconds. Once you actually multiplied them out, you would have seen that it gave you negative your bottom row.

Comment: Not my point, but let's move on.

Comment: You should have a $1/2$ in the third row.

Comment: I figured out the correct $L$ and $U$, thanks though.